# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotVisibleException tring to select a span element

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to navigate a website that stores documents related to several projects. To get to a specific project I need to search a project name by inputting it in the search bar and selecting from the search result. I am able to find the search bar and search for the project that I am interested in but, trying to click on the searched project gives me "element is not visible" exception.

There is also a recently viewed projects section and I can select every project in this list except the first one. This does not help my use case though as the project, that I am searching for, might not always be in the recently viewed list. And I cannot select the first project in this list (But that is a different question maybe for some other time)

Here is the python code that I am using

```
change_proj = find_element.ret_element_handle(browser, 'xpath', '//td/em/button[text()="Change project"]')
change_proj.click()
print("after change_proj")

# Search bar in pop up window to change project

search_bar = browser.find_elements_by_name("searchString")
search_bar[1].send_keys(projectName)

project = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(., '" + projectName + "')]")

project.click() 
# This is the line that generates the exception
```

With the great help available on internet, I have tried a) waiting for element to be clickable, b) moving to the element "project" using `ActionChains` c) trying different version of the xpath that looks for a specific text but, none of these have worked.

I am attaching the html of the page as the image (Some entries are blanked out for confidentiality) [image: image for the page html]

Comment: is the element visible on initial page load or do you have to scroll down to make it visible?  which element from your image are you attempting to click?

Comment: element becomes visible once I input the name in the search bar. I have tried waiting. So timing does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: Do you mean after you search for the project (input in search bar and hit enter), the element is present in the html-source?  Anyway, I think it will be difficult for someone to assist without specifics or ability to replicate your situation.  If feasible, create a dummy example of the problem you're encountering that can be replicated.